# Ajaxcontrolkit calendar control - customisation

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

Can the calendar control be customsised so that, say you have a system of renting out a holiday home. can the dates that have been booked appear as red and disabled on the ajaxcalendar control?

Cheers -- Jonesy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run forest - run away from the ajax control toolkit. jQuery is your friend.

Heres a link to the jquery Ui calendar. Other good plug-ins exists as well as other good javascript libraries, but MS is getting behind jQuery and jQuery UI is the official UI library.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: the thing i love about the ajax control toolkit is its just so easy to use (apart from the question this post is about!). Like adding a calendar for a simple date picker. Just click on the text box and add the calendar extender! How does this compare to jQuery?

Comment: I've started a discussion about the Ajaxcontroltoolkit and jQuery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628664/ajaxcontroltoolkit-vs-jquery

Comment: Its interesting that others feel the same way - I think the upfront investment in getting into jQuery will help you later with lots of things relating to javascript and client side dev.